# swift ios how to access data from a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have code below in a collection view and its result, what I want to know is how to access those data from my collection view to my function prepare. I want to get the value of `getTempDetails` like

```
getTempDetails["name"] as! String
```

to be the value of my

```
destination.chore_name = getTempDetails["name"] as! String
```

but I can't seem to access it. thanks

code for prepare

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let distanation = segue.destination as? ChoreDetailsViewController {
            distanation.chore_name  = "Hi"
        }
    }
```

code for

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
//        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
//        print("emong gepili:" , titleArray[indexPath.row])

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSegue", sender: nil)
        } else {
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoDetails", sender: nil)
            print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
            if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["reward"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["desc"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["sched"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
```

Comment: store getTempDetails in class var before calling performSegue and pass this var in prepareForSegue method

Comment: can you post your answer so i can upvote. Thanks

Comment: Yes storing that in a variable will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the keyword of `indexPathsForSelectedItems` for colletionview

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
      if segue.identifier == "gotoDetails" , 
       let nextScene = segue.destination as? ChoreDetailsViewController , 
       let indexPath = self.yourCollectionViewName. indexPathsForSelectedItems().first  {
        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.item] {
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["reward"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["desc"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
                print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["sched"] as? String  ?? "" )!")

     nextScene.chore_name = getTempDetails["name"] as! String
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: indexPathsForSelectedItems can return multiple IndexPaths so in this case you have to specify correct index

Comment: @tereks- thanks my bro, answer updated using `().first `

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can use:

```
var strReward:String = String()
var strDesc:String = String()
var sreSched:String = String()


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSegue", sender: nil)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoDetails", sender: nil)
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
            strReward = (getTempDetails["reward"] as? String)!
            strDesc = (getTempDetails["desc"] as? String)!
            sreSched = (getTempDetails["sched"] as? String)!
        }
    }
}
```

Pass this Data to next VC or can use them in any way you want

**Note:-** I am not sure what data type is the data coming, I have assumed it to be a `String` type. You can use accordingly

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Can you please explain why.? This may help me correcting my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can store last selected items data in class var

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSegue", sender: nil)
        } else {
            if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row],
            let name = getTempDetails["name"] as? String {
              selectedChoreName = name
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoDetails", sender: nil)
            }
```

and then

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let distanation = segue.destination as? ChoreDetailsViewController {
            distanation.chore_name = selectedChoreName
            selectedChoreName = "" //optional
        }
    }
```

Comment: appreciated both of your anwer. Thanks

Comment: why you created the another instance , you can directly access the object

Comment: @Anbu.karthik instance of what?

Comment: @tereks - for this variable `selectedChoreName`

Comment: This is one way of using it. In my code I restrict segue to be called if no data is available, and in addition save last selected cell's data. That can be useful if we flush collectionView on appear

Comment: @tereks , Hey Sir, how about ifi wanted to pass multipl datas?

Comment: so that would be    if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row],
            let name = getTempDetails["name"] as? String , let id = getTempDetails["id"] as? String { and so on?